# Django template alternative to the `with` tag

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django templates, it is possible to introduce a new named variable to the context using the `with` tag:

```
{% with total=business.employees.count %}
    {{ total }} employee{{ total|pluralize }}
{% endwith %}
```

I find myself often using it to rename variables so that I can include re-usable templates:

```
{% with user_list=request.user.friends %}
    {% include '_user_list.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Is there a way to introduce a new variable in the context without using the `with` tag? I am imagining a tag like `set` where you call it once like `{% set user_list=request.user.friends %}` and then do not need to close it off with a `{% endset %}` tag. This is something akin to the `{% trans "This is the title" as the_title %}` in function.

If there is not a way to do this, what are some reasons why this is not a good / pythonic / django-way of doing things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [`include` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include), you'll see that you can assign and pass variables to the template within the tag itself:

> You can pass additional context to the template using keyword arguments:

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}
```

Comment: This is great. I have no idea how I missed this. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Yea I think it's a newish feature (maybe >= 1.3) but very useful